# Convert JSON Timestamp to date and time format

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7

```
{
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "expiry": 1704784131,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "sadsadadasd"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.example.com",
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "PHPSESSID",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "sdfsadadasdasdas"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "expiry": 1678000126,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gcl_au",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "sdfsdsadadas"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".example.com",
    "expiry": 1670310531,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gid",
    "path": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "sdfsdfasdiajidjais"
  },
```

I want to convert JSON timestamp

```
"expiry": 1704784131,
```

Into date and time format. But expiry not present in every node.

My JSON format is in above code please check and help me out from this problem.

Comment: From your question, it is not clear to me whether you are stuck with extracting the _expiry_ values, or how to convert them. I also don't understand, why the question is tagged with so many different programming languages (bash, Python 2.7, Python 3); please make up your mind first in which language you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

expiry = 1670310531
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(expiry))
```

Result:

```
2022-12-06 08:08:51
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, 

Yes we can change the value by using your code, 

but i need to change it in the out.json file for all the values not for only one value.

Comment: @Learnernoob Ok, use a for loop and run through each section saving or printing the expiry values while converting them.

Comment: hey @user56700 can you please write a code for the same.